# How to get MySQL JSON_OBJECT from a table row?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a selection of a row to retrieve key-value pairs for a `JSON` output. Therefore I tried this:

```
SELECT  
    JSON_OBJECT(
        COLUMN_NAME, (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM 'tbl_name' WHERE ID = 'pID')
    )
FROM    
    information_schema.columns
WHERE   
    TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_name' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();
```

Unfortunately the `COLUMN_NAME` in the `SELECT` is not handled as string and the value is not shown. My question is, how can I fix this and getting it to work?

Please note: This query shall be used later inside a `TRIGGER`. I found several solutions to convert a row into JSON. But these solutions are using procedures and dynamic SQL. But MySQL doesn't support dynamic SQL in triggers. So I need to find another way to convert a row into JSON. I'm looking for a general approach, because many tables with many columns shall be triggered. That's why it is not really comfortable to create the `JSON_OBJECT` line-by-line and I'm looking for a method do it via the `COLUMN_NAME`

Comment: If you want a generic solution with dynamic column and table names, then you do need dynamic sql, there is no workaround that in mysql at the moment, which indicates that your approach is not going to work. You can either have triggers with non-dynamic sql and therefore bespoke to a specific data structure or you can have a dynamic solution, but that cannot be invoked from a trigger.

Comment: @Shadow thx for your feedback. That's a bit I already had afraid...